# retrieve username and nickname from active directory on local network

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, active-directory

I want to read the username and NickName of any users on my local network from server's active directory. How can I do it? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void getUser()
{
 DirectoryServices.SearchResult myResult;
 string filterString = string.Empty;
 string EntryString = "LDAP:// <Your AD Domain here>";
 DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher myDirectorySearcher = new DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(EntryString, "Username", "Password"));
 string tempStr;
 string[] splStr = new string[3];

 filterString = "(sAMAccountName=" + Username + ")";
 myDirectorySearcher.Filter = filterString;
 myDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
 myResult = myDirectorySearcher.FindOne();
 splStr = Regex.Split(myResult.Properties("cn").Item(0).ToString, " ");
 tempStr = splStr(1).ToString + " " + splStr(0).ToString;
 Label1.Text = "Hello " + tempStr;
}
```

Comment: @rmcdonald:with this code both username and nickname i can see??

Comment: sorry, to add other fields just use myDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(). For example, to get givenname (which I think is nickname):
myDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname")

Comment: @rmcdonald:i'm new programmer ,sorry,you mean i can add 2 properties to myDirectorySearcher??myDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
  and myDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname") ok??

Comment: Yes, you can add as many as you want and you can access them the same way 'cn' is accessed. myResult.Properties("givenname").Item(0).ToString()

Comment: @rmcdonald:"DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"my domain);
            DirectorySearcher myDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry); " if i change your code ,with this code i can get the properties of any users,is it true??

Comment: @rmcdonald:and this changes:"myResult = myDirectorySearcher.FindAll();"